# How to make my PHP output two values from database

Tags: php, html, variables, select

Ive included a block of code below detailling how im placing sections of data from a table in my database in their own divs. However, im new to PHP and cant find out how to also output the "cup_id" from the database into their respective divs here: `echo $cup["cup_name"] . "<br />";` Thanks for all the help in advance!

So in short how do i get this to work: `echo $cup["cup_id", "cup_name"] . "<br />";`

```
<?php
require_once("action/dbcon.php"); // Get the database connection
$get_cup = "SELECT * FROM cups";
$show_cup = mysqli_query($conn, $get_cup);

if (!$show_cup) {
    echo "Could not load cup. " . "(" . mysqli_error($conn) . ")";
}

while ($cup = mysqli_fetch_assoc($show_cup)) {
    echo '<div class="cup-info">';
    echo $cup["cup_name"] . "<br />";
    echo '</div>';
}
?>
```

Comment: echo the column individually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want to concatenate strings? use the dot operator:

```
echo $cup["cup_id"] . $cup["cup_name"];
```

And if you want to print it in another div, make this:

```
echo '<div class="cup-info">';
echo $cup["cup_id"] . "<br />";
echo '</div>';
echo '<div class="cup-info">';
echo $cup["cup_name"] . "<br />";
echo '</div>';
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want the name and id to be in the same raw then you can follow this method

```
<?php
require_once("action/dbcon.php"); // Get the database connection
$get_cup = "SELECT * FROM cups";
$show_cup = mysqli_query($conn, $get_cup);

if (!$show_cup) {
    echo "Could not load cup. " . "(" . mysqli_error($conn) . ")";
}

while ($cup = mysqli_fetch_assoc($show_cup)) {
    echo '<div class="cup-info">';
    echo $cup["cup_id"] . $cup["cup_name"]."<br />";
    echo '</div>';
}
?>
```

if you want the name and id to be in different raw then you can follow this method

```
<?php
require_once("action/dbcon.php"); // Get the database connection
$get_cup = "SELECT * FROM cups";
$show_cup = mysqli_query($conn, $get_cup);

if (!$show_cup) {
    echo "Could not load cup. " . "(" . mysqli_error($conn) . ")";
}

while ($cup = mysqli_fetch_assoc($show_cup)) {
    echo '<div class="cup-info">';
    echo $cup["cup_id"]."<br />";
    echo '</div>';
    echo '<div class="cup-info">';
    echo $cup["cup_name"]."<br />";
    echo '</div>';
}
?>
```